# iOS Selection Widgets Over Image

Tags: ios, textselection

I'd like to use the iOS text selection widgets over an image. The image contains text, and I have programmatic access to glyph positions and text strings. I have searched high and low and cannot see in Apple's documentation or anywhere online how to display/manipulate the text selection widgets. Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Thanks!